# PHPmailer: allow copy of email to be sent to sender if they check a box

Tags: php, email, checkbox, phpmailer

I want users to be able to select a box that says "Send me a copy of the email" after completing a form. I'm using phpMailer to send the form to myself, and I don't know how to add a second email address under the condition that the person selected this box. Right now I have:

```
if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
    $senderEmail = $email;
}
```

and

```
<li>
<h4>Send me a copy of this form</h4>
<input type="radio" id="send" name="send">
<label for="send">Yes please</label>

<input type="radio" id="nosend" name="nosend">
<label for="nosend">No, thank you</label>
</li>
```

and finally

```
include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($email, $firstname);
$mail->addAddress('email@address.com'); 
$mail->addAddress($senderEmail);
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New email from ' . $name;
$mail->Body    = "

<h2>Email from your Website</h2>
<p>Name: $firstname $lastname </p>
<p>Email: $email </p>
<p>Phone: $phone </p>
<p>Country: $
<p>Message: $comments </p>


";
```

Also, while we're looking at it, in the Body of the email as listed above, I want to get the information for Country which is in a dropdown selection menu. If anyone can also tell me how to do this, as well as how to do the same from whichever selection a sender makes from a radio checklist, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Try to keep your question focused on one request. This will keep answers more clear and concise. It will also make it easier for you to checkmark the correct answer. Consider removing your last paragraph and posting it as a separate question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/300177
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/300177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending two parameters `nosend` and `send` when you only need one: `send`. That one will be either `true` or `false` depending on which radio is selected. Note that both their names are `send` now and I added `value` attributes.

```
<input type="radio" id="send" name="send" value="true">
<input type="radio" id="nosend" name="send" value="false">
```

Since there are only two options, it might make more sense to use a checkbox instead of radios. Radio inputs are more appropriate when there are more than two options.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="send" name="send" value="true">
```

Then, in you're mailing logic, only add the additional address if the `send` parameter is set to the appropriate value.

```
$mail->addAddress('email@address.com'); 
if (isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == 'true') {
    $mail->addAddress($senderEmail);
}
```